# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cblas_dgemm referenced in function _main

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm using the Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL) on top of my Visual studio C/C++ compiler. I've set my Additional include directories, Additional library directories, Additional dependencies variables in order to link to the MKL library, but when I ran the matrix multiplication sample code I still got linking errors, can anybody tell me what did I miss there?

```
#define min(x,y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mkl.h"

int main()
{
double *A, *B, *C;
int m, n, p, i, j;
double alpha, beta;
m = 2000, p = 200, n = 1000;
alpha = 1.0; beta = 0.0;

A = (double *)mkl_malloc( m*p*sizeof( double ), 64 );
B = (double *)mkl_malloc( p*n*sizeof( double ), 64 );
C = (double *)mkl_malloc( m*n*sizeof( double ), 64 );
if (A == NULL || B == NULL || C == NULL) {
  printf( "\n ERROR: Can't allocate memory for matrices. Aborting... \n\n");
  mkl_free(A);
  mkl_free(B);
  mkl_free(C);
  return 1;
}

printf (" Intializing matrix data \n\n");
for (i = 0; i < (m*p); i++) {
    A[i] = (double)(i+1);
}

for (i = 0; i < (p*n); i++) {
    B[i] = (double)(-i-1);
}

for (i = 0; i < (m*n); i++) {
    C[i] = 0.0;
}

printf (" Computing matrix product using Intel® MKL dgemm function via CBLAS interface \n\n");
cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 
            m, n, p, alpha, A, p, B, n, beta, C, n);

mkl_free(A);
mkl_free(B);
mkl_free(C);

printf (" Example completed. \n\n");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MKL Link line advisor](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor).
Additionally you may follow the steps in [this link](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-compiling-and-linking-with-microsoft-visual-cc) to link MKL with microsoft visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell since the source code is not really that useful for linker errors. If the linker says it can't find a function, then you're not linking the correct libraries, regardless of whether the source successfully compiled or not.

One thing I'd look for, it does no good to just specify the library *directories* since they just give different search paths to look at when locating libraries. You still need to specify the actual library itself that you want to link with.

That's one possible cause based on the information in your question.